# Services module update date field

Tags: 7, services

Hi i am using drupal services 3 module. Every thing is perfect except updating date field. I tried many ways to update that field but didn't get any solution. Is any core issue related to date field?

Comment: Please add everything you've actually tried into the question, including code. Also add in all of the error messages you've received, what steps you've taken to debug the issue yourself, and what problems you've found there. It's impossible for us to debug your Drupal installation from here, so you'll need to add a **lot** more detail to your question if it's to be useful to future visitors, and subsequently remain open. If this is a bug report you need to take it to the Services module issue queue, we can't accept bug reports here. Thanks :)

Comment: I will update the code ASAP.

Comment: Thanks. To preempt that - no, there's no general problem with services and date fields, I use them all the time

Comment: @Clive, i am facing issues with date field too. they never get saved.

Comment: @NikhilM Interesting, like I say I've never had a problem. I've literally just run one as a test and it worked fine...

Comment: @NikhilM Are we talking about fields provided by the Date module? And if so what type? (timestamp, etc.)

Comment: @Clive, yes i have a date of birth field in user profile and i am still facing issues with submission.

Comment: Yes, I found if a date string supplied via a web service has the "wrong" format the Date module silently ignores the value. This is really unhelpful. Two possible solutions: write your own validator which is more flexible, or alter the client so it sends in the required format.

Answer (score 7):

it depends on the field widget how you submit your values for the service.
For instance when you have a date field (datetime) with a select/dropdown widget, the form of the value should be the following:

```
"field_date":{"und":[{"value":{"month":"3","year":"2013","day":"6","hour":"0","minute":"0","second":"0"}}]},
```

Comment: Or for datetime picker... "field_date": {
        "und": [
            {
                "value": {
                   "date": "07/16/2013",
                   "time": "11:14am"
                }
            }
        ]
    },

Comment: @30equals, your answer helped me determine what values to send via a URL data string, thanks! For example, "&node[field_date][und][0][value][year]=2013", works for a 'Date' field type that uses a 'Select list' widget and a 'Year' granularity.

Comment: @30equals, Can I post a timestamp format to drupal via android device?