# Field value not updating when posting data via JSON

Tags: services

Here I am getting 200 response but the date field over here is not getting updated.

The node is getting created and other fields are getting updated, only this date field is not getting created.

the error which iam  getting 
[image]
The Json and content type format is below:

```
"field_date_of_cage_card_creation": {
        "und": [
            {
                 "date":"17 Dec 2018",
                  "time":"02:45 pm",

                "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
                "timezone_db": "Asia/Kolkata",
                "date_type": "datetime"


            }
        ]
    },
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check with timestamp rather than date and time.

Comment: @AjayReddy can you please tell me the format

Comment: strtotime("17 Dec 2018 02:45 pm"); it will give timestamp as "1545038100" and pass this timestamp in date value.

Comment: @AjayReddy this wont work as the service is created via content type so need to pass in some other way

Comment: @AjayReddy i tried your way not workin

Comment: On your `Manage fields` page for this content type, what type of `Widget` is listed for your date field?

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein     Date -- Pop-up calendar

Comment: This Q/A may be useful: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/66022/10645

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding your date in the value property and not including a time.

```
"field_date_of_cage_card_creation": {
    "und": [
        {
            "value":"17 Dec 2018",
            // or maybe
            "value":"2018-12-17",
            "timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
            "timezone_db": "Asia/Kolkata",
            "date_type": "datetime"
        }
    ]
},
```